# Why does my return value increase itself in an object in Java?

Tags: java, class, object

I am new to Java and learnt about classes and making objects recently.

I am working on my assignment and I can't figure out why this is happening.

What I want to achieve:

I have a Main.java class and HouseQuote.java class. I am creating 3 HouseQuote objects by calling them on Main.java. I have to calculate the total cost of the House in HouseQuote class under `calculateCost` method.
The price of house depends on the size of Kitchen, DIning, number of rooms which I will be passing through parameters.

Here's my main.java:

```
package assignment1;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String args[] ){  
        System.out.println("==============================================================================");
        System.out.println("Welcome to Comfort Homes. We will show you quotes for 4 different houses here.");
        System.out.println("==============================================================================");

        System.out.println("\n");

        
        //call houses 
        
        HouseQuote h4 = new HouseQuote("Small", "Large", 5);
        System.out.println(h4);
        System.out.println("\n");
    
        HouseQuote h1 = new HouseQuote("Small", "Large", 5);
        System.out.println(h1);
        System.out.println("\n");
        
        HouseQuote h2 = new HouseQuote("Small", "Large", 5);
        System.out.println(h2);
        System.out.println("\n");
        
 }
}
```

I am using same size of kitchen and dining and numbers of rooms in all three houses to show the problem.

Here is my HouseQuote.java class:

```
package assignment1;

public class HouseQuote {

    //assigning variables
    
    public  int baseCost = 60000; //base cost of the house is $60k
    public static int totalCost=0; //total cost of the house. 

        
        //kitchen
    String kitchenSize;
    public  int smallKitchenCost = 6000; 
    public  int largeKitchenCost = 12000;
        
        //dining 
    String diningSize;
    public  int smallDiningCost = 4000;
    public  int largeDiningCost = 9000;
        
        //bedrooms
    int noOfBedrooms;
    public  int uptoThreeRoomsCost = 5000; //cost up to 3 rooms is 5k each
    public  int extraBedRoomCost = 4000;   //cost of extra bedroom is 4k each
        
HouseQuote(String kitchenSize, String diningSize, int noOfBedRooms) { 
    
        
        this.kitchenSize = kitchenSize;
        this.diningSize = diningSize;
        this.noOfBedrooms = noOfBedRooms;
    
        System.out.println(totalCost);

        
        //check kitchen size
        if (kitchenSize == "Large") {
            calculateCost(largeKitchenCost);
        }
        else {
            calculateCost(smallKitchenCost);
        }
    
        //check dining size
        if (diningSize == "Large") {
            calculateCost(largeDiningCost);
        }
        else {
            calculateCost(smallDiningCost);
        }
        
        //check number of bed rooms
        if (noOfBedRooms <=3) {
            //less than or equal to three, add costs of each room to total
            calculateCost(noOfBedRooms * uptoThreeRoomsCost);
            
        }
        else {
            //find out how many extra rooms
            int extraRooms = noOfBedRooms - 3;
            // add price for three bedroom plus extra 
            calculateCost((uptoThreeRoomsCost * 3) + (extraBedRoomCost * extraRooms));
        }
        
    }
        
            
    
    public void calculateCost(int costInThisStep) {
        totalCost = totalCost + costInThisStep; 
    }
    
    public String toString() {
     return  (kitchenSize + " kitchen" + "\n" ) + (diningSize + " Dining" + "\n" ) +  (noOfBedrooms + " Bedrooms" + "\n" ) + "Total cost: " + (totalCost+baseCost);


    }
        
}
```

Output:

```
    ============================================================================= Welcome to Comfort Homes. We will show you quotes for 4 different houses here.
    ==============================================================================
    
    
    0
Small kitchen 
Large Dining 
5 Bedrooms 
Total cost: 98000
    
    
    38000 
Small kitchen 
Large Dining 
5 Bedrooms 
Total cost: 136000
    
    
    76000 
Small kitchen 
Large Dining 
5 Bedrooms 
Total cost: 174000
```

As you can see, the first calculation is correct. The price should be 98k for all the houses. However, the second time it's 38k extra and then 76k extra. I noticed that the 38k extra is the same number as the price of houses without the `baseCost` which is 60k.

I am guessing I need to reset the value of TotalCost somewhere? But I don't know where. I tried doing that after returning the output inside '  public String toString() {' but it didn't work.

Some help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: okay I AM STUPID. i feel so stupid. Right after I made this post I realized I can reset TotalCost = 0; right before I start calculating the costs.

Comment: Even better: Don't mutate some internal counter. Instead, make your method start a local variable from zero and return it at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static variables in classes are shared between objects.
So the variable `totalCost` is shared between all the `HouseQuote` objects.
When the `h4` object is initialized, the value of the `totalCost` is 38,000.

When the second object initialized, the value wont reset, and it will start at 38,000. That's the reason for the gap as far as I can see.

The simple solution is to remove the static field in the `HouseQuote` variable, and then each instance will be with their own `totalCost`.

Comment: thank you! This not solves this problem but also removes other extra lines of code I had to write to reset other counters. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In Java you don't compare two Strings if they contain same letters by `==`, but by method `equals`.
Try instead `kitchenSize == "Large"`, `kitchenSize.equals("Large")`.

Comment: thank you. in what case would you use == ?

Comment: == you use when want comprare if two String variables have reference to same instances. Like: String s1 = "HelloWord" and s2 = s1, then s1 == s2 is true.

Comment: But there is also one detail. If: String s1 = "HelloWord"  and String s2 = "HelloWord", then s1 == s2 is also true.  There is optimization, Java sees "HelloWord" is same literal, so it creates only one instance for both variables and s1 and s2 have again reference to same instance.
If you breke optimalization for example this way by different creating String instances: String s1 = "HelloWord" and s2 =  new String ("HelloWord")  , then s1 == s2 is not true.